# Transpose data in HIVE

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, transpose

I have the following dataset in Hive, and I would like to transpose rows into columns.

| Customer | Status | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | Paid | 5 |
| 25 | N Paid | 2 |
| 67 | Open | 12 |
| 67 | Paid | 4 |
| 45 | N Paid | 3 |
| 45 | Open | 2 |

I would like to have a new table after transpose that shows only one line by a customer and multiple columns by Status, e.g.

| Customer | Paid | N Paid | Open |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | 5 | 2 | 0 |
| 67 | 4 | 0 | 12 |
| 45 | 0 | 3 | 2 |

I tried some examples I've found on the Internet, but I could not make it works. Here, for the sake of simplicity, I listed only three statuses, but in fact, I could have more than that.

In SAS, I used to did something such as the following:

```
proc transpose
   data = imputtable;
   out = outputtable;
   by customer;
   id status;
   var quantity;
run;
```

SAS gets all the existing statuses and pivots them into columns. I was looking to do the same in Hive.

Regards,

Marcio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select Customer, 
       sum(case when Status = 'Paid'   then Quantity else 0 end) as Paid     ,
       sum(case when Status = 'N Paid' then Quantity else 0 end) as `N Paid` ,
       sum(case when Status = 'Open'   then Quantity else 0 end) as Open
 from table
group by Customer
```

Comment: Is there any way to get all the status without mentioning them in the CASE clause? As the SAS example, I added.

Comment: @MarcioLino Not possible in Hive, it does not support dynamic SQL.